# EventStore Projections when to use them

Tags: javascript, eventstoredb

I've been looking at Event Store for a little while now and one thing that stumped me is when should one consider writing a projection? Is it common practice to create a flattened projection?

> The setup here is using a stream per aggregate

For example, lets say I have 2 events that look like this:

```
public class OrderPlaced
{
    public OrderPlaced(string reference, Currency currency, Amount amount)
    {
        ...
    }

    public string Reference { get; }

    public Currency Currency { get; } //Custom type

    public Amount Amount { get; } //Custom type
}

public class OrderCompleted
{
    public OrderCompleted(string reference)
    {
        this.Reference = reference;
    }

    public string Reference { get; }
}
```

I have the following query:

```
fromCategory('MyCategory')
  .whenAny(function(s, e) {
      linkTo("Foo", e);
  })
```

The above doesn't do a great deal and only aggregates all the streams into a singular. Is it possible to project a view that is more flat, for example into something like this? Perhaps I got my wires crossed but apparently using `emit` can achieve this?

```
{
    string Reference;
    string CurrencyCode;
    decimal PayingAmount;
}
```

My thinking is, once I have written to the stream I can guarantee the aggregate is in a valid state and thus for any interested parties I should only expose the fields these processes require. Is projecting a simple model (a de-nomarlized view) the correct thing to do..

The above is a trivial example, but you can imagine an aggregate being a little more complicated.

If I have missed anything or further clarification is needed then please comment and I can add.

Comment: Sounds fine to me. I think Projections are still currently in beta though - supposed to be coming in 4.0.0. Have you read through the existing projections docs? http://docs.geteventstore.com. In a project I worked on we used the built in projections when we had some simple state we wanted to query (usernames had to be unique, so we maintained a usernames projection across user aggregates / streams).

Comment: I've read the docs and they lack a little detail for me at least. Is it possible to load a stream in the query so you can pull the entire aggregate? This is so that if I get event 2, load the entire aggregate, grab info from both event 1 and 2 and create a flattened view. Is this possible?

Comment: You can subscribe to the category that represents your aggregate (in my example, 'users') then use simple JavaScript statements to determine what to do with each event type... I.e. If event type = eventtype1 {} etc

Comment: Also, try the event store google group if Stack Overflow isn't helping :)

Comment: I'm going to ask on there now :) cheers for the suggestion

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a standard event category projection.

It emits linked events to steam that are called ´$ce-´. The category there is your object type.

For example, your aggregate type is `Order`, and you write events `OrderCreated`, `OrderLineAdded`, etc to streams with names `Order-1`, `Order-2`, where 1 and 3 are your aggregate root ids. Then, the `$ce-Order` stream will contain all events for all aggregates of that type.

Have a look at the [standard projections documentation](http://docs.geteventstore.com/projections/4.0.0/system-projections/).

Usually this is exactly the way to create read-side projections - by creating a catch-up subscription on category streams and updating the read model accordingly.

In order to run projections, you need to use `--run-projections=all –-start-standard-projections=true` to see it working.